# Magento 2 - Order Cancellation Charges

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status

I want to reduce 1% of the total ordered amount when someone cancels an order.

So even though an order is canceled, the customer still has to pay 1% of the total amount he ordered.

How do I achieve this? Do we have an extension for this as an alternate way?

Answer (score 0):

Credit memo is a default way of refunding in Magento.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/sales/credit-memos.html

Now, I've made one order with subtotal `45.0`, shipping cost `5.0` and tax `3.71`.
The total of it `53.71`.

I need to have an invoice made, after which the status of the order moved to `processing`, and at this point I could make a new credit memo.

Eventually I get this view

[image]

Which means that I have partial control over what is being refunded.
In this case all items are to be refunded, so the subtotal is 45, and the tax bound to it, normally, cannot be changed.

However, I can choose to refund shipping or not.

At it seems, your question is still not answered, and I will not pretend to know if the default credit memo entity can be used exactly for what you need.

But, it is good to keep in mind that credit memo can be created programatically, and the process will be very simmilar to making an order.

That given, then maybe it is possible to extend the credit memo to add new total named `Cancelation Fee` that will subtract, as opposed to the addition that `Adjustment Fee` already makes.

Needless to say you could do something like

```
$cancelationFee = 0.01 * $grandTotal;
$creditMemo->setCancelationFee($cancelationFee);
$creditMemo->create(); (or whatever the method is that would create the memo)
```

So, this is just an idea that I had. I hope it helps.